# How to hide the close button of a fancybox based on a click within the fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

We are currently using Fancybox2.

On the first webpage, we click on a link to open a fancybox. Then inside the fancybox we have additional links. We want to be able to click on a link INSIDE the fancybox, which would then hide the top right close button.

Here is the code that we have on the first webpage.

`$(".popupwindow").fancybox({
                padding: 0,
                margin : 50,
                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 200,
                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                closeSpeed  : 150,
                scrolling : 'visible',
                width : '1040px',
                height : '90%',
                maxWidth : 1100,
                closeClick : false,
                iframe  :  {
                    scrolling : 'auto',
                    preload   : true
                            }
}`

And here is the code that launches the fancybox

`<a href="somewhere" class="popupwindow">Open fancybox </a>`

Now we are in the fancybox.

On the link click we have an id `<a id="myTest">Something</a>`

Then we track the clicks using this...

```
$("#myTest").click(function(){

//At this point I'd like to hide the fancybox close button on top right.

}
```

We know that if we put parent.$.fancybox.close() inside the function above, it will close the fancybox, however, how do we go about hiding the close button? Not sure what the syntax is.

We see the following documentation on the website, and have tried multiple variations of it, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers: {
     closeBtn: false
   }
 });
```

Comment: does your close button have any name or id or class? Also can you post the HTML as well, and how you are detecting the link click event

Comment: No the close button does not have a name or class. I posted some additional HTML and Jquery in the original post to show how we are doing it, including how to detect the click event. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
$(.fancybox-close).hide(); //hides it
...
$(.fancybox-close).show(); //shows it
```